# Where can I find the different OS partions made with Berryboot on an SD-card?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, openelec, partition

I have installed Raspbian and [OpenELEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenELEC) with Berryboot. I now want to locate and change a file on the OpenELEC partion. I can't change it in OpenELEC as it lacks an editor.

So I have to locate the file through Raspbian or another computer where I plug the SD-card in. The problem is, I can't seem to find the OpenELEC partion. There's only two showing, a Berryboot-partion with OS-images and other files, and a boot-partion with config.txt, etc...
How can I see the OpenELEC partion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenELEC distribution uses squashfs [1] which is read-only. If you installed OpenELEC with Berryboot, you have to had folders named `/data` `/images` on your SD card or USB stick. So if you want to edit a file which changed by OpenELEC you can find it in `/data` folder. Put your SD card into another computer, find the data folder, and edit it.

To change boot files, such as config.txt, you have to mount your SD card in another computer with `mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt` command, then go into /mnt folder and edit your file.

By the way, /images folder contains your Linux distribution images which are downloaded by Berryboot.

The second way to edit OpenELEC files is to uncompress the OpenELEC image file with the unsquashfs tool. First install squashfs-tools,

```
apt-get install squashfs-tools

mkdir /openelec
cd /openelec
unsquashfs /mnt/images/OpenELEC.img
cd /openelec/squashfs-root/
```

Edit your files then:

```
cd /openelec
mksquashfs /openelec OpenELEC-modified.img
```

And put the modified image into the /images folder in Berryboot.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squashfs

Comment: Thank you very much, you are absolutely right. The files are stored in /data, the reason I couldn't see them was because they where hidden. A beginners mistake...